# How to monitor Javascript calls in WKWebView Swift?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I currently have an ios application using WKWebView to load HTML. Sometimes the HTML has buttons or links that execute javascript. For example, the search button on Google executes a javascript command to load the page. I was wondering if it is possible to monitor these javascript calls in the WKWebView. I know you can monitor activated links, but I don't know of a way to monitor javascript calls.

Comment: You can make use of WKScriptMessageHandler to do the job but for that Javascript should post message using window.webkit.messageHandlers.observe.postMessage so if you have a access to javascript you can always use this